# ansible playbook execute in this order: task, role, task, role, task

Tags: ansible

Forgive my newbie question, but I would like to execute three tasks and use two roles in a playbook, in the order:

1. task
2. role
3. task
4. role
5. task

This is what I have so far (task, role, task):

```
---
- name: Task Role Task
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:
   - name: Do this task first
     foo:

  roles:
  - role: this role second
    foo:

  post_tasks: 
   - name: Do this task third
     foo:
```

Is this possible or should I be changing my tasks into roles?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I recommend you create roles for post and pre tasks for you ansible.

Your site.yml must be some like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: "{{remote_user}}"
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - pre
    - main_role
    - post
```

in roles folder you must have three roles, pre, post and main_role.

Comment: This is the correct approach since it will work correctly for rolling updates,  unlike using separate hosts sections.

Answer (score 32):

```
---
- name: Task Role Task
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: task1
      foo: 

    - name: include role1
      include_role: 
        name: myrole1

    - name: task2
      foo:

    - name: include role2
      include_role: 
        name: myrole2
```

see official [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_role_module.html)

Comment: From my point of view, _this_ is the real answer to this question. But maybe it wasn't available back then when the question was initially asked.

Comment: There is also "import_role" which may be relevant. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_role_module.html

Comment: Since Ansible 2.2 (September 2016) this is the correct answer.

Comment: Import (static behavior) should be used to mimic same behavior as roles directive. See doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level

Answer (score 26):

Each "hosts:"-block will be executed one by one. So you can use multiple blocks to force the desired execution order:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
   - name: Do this task first

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  roles:
  - role: this role second

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
   - name: Do this task third
```

Comment: A gotcha with this approach is if you decide to attempt to use rolling updates and intend for the set of plays to execute sequentially.  Instead of completing everything serially, each play will complete for the entire set of hosts!